# android studio, only on real mobile, " ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed " "Failed to start monitoring ##"

Tags: android, adb

Please help. In Android studio 4.0, when attached USB with real mobile, it will continuing to show connect & dis-connect on-and-off forever. Error is : " ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed ". "Failed to start monitoring K4AXB760P480AX9" Just from yesterday, when I`m trying my app using in real mobile. The same mobile used to be OK in the same notebook android studio. It is still OK for now in same notebook for virtual device. The same mobile is OK in other notebook android studio.

Comment: Hi did u solve this issue? I am facing same thing today in Android HedgeHog